Safari extension – context menu item renders TWICE
I render three new context menu items through a Safari extension like this:
browser.contextMenus.create({
  id: 'copy-this',
  title: 'Copy this',
  contexts: ['selection', 'link']
});

browser.contextMenus.create({
  id: 'copy-that',
  title: 'Copy that',
  contexts: ['selection', 'link']
});

browser.contextMenus.create({
  id: 'do-this',
  title: 'Do this',
  contexts: ['selection', 'link']
});

When right clicking on regular text, these menu items render fine. Just once per.
I don’t even specify editable contexts, and yet when the user right clicks on text in a textarea, say, the above menu items render twice.
Ideally, they shouldn’t render at all in editable contexts. How do I do that?

Could it be because contexts: ['selection', 'link'] includes the "selection" context, which is also triggered when selecting text inside an editable field (like a textarea)? Safari's browser.contextMenus.create doesn't automatically filter out editable contexts when "selection" is specified.

I’ve been wondering that, too. It strikes me as a bug in Safari because I don’t see any reason any menu items should ever render twice. If I remove 'selection', that will presumably get rid of the problem, but I can’t remove it because I need it for non-editable contexts.

I see you are not getting much traction here. Does this work for you?

Looks promising, but I’m afraid browser.contextMenus.onShown is undefined. Inspecting browser.contextMenus, it looks like the only available event is onClick.
